# Can't run Python in asp.net core web API project

Tags: python, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, nuget

I'm using Core 6 and Pythonnet package.

I create a Python file name example.py

```
def add(a, b):
return a + b
```

I create a class name `PythonScriptRunner`:

```
public PythonScriptRunner()
{
    Runtime.PythonDLL = @"C:\Python312\python312.dll"; // I installed the python it this path
    PythonEngine.Initialize();
}
```

and add it in program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<PythonScriptRunner>();
```

then I create a Controller

```
public IActionResult Test(int a, int b)
{
     using (Py.GIL())
     {
         dynamic python = Py.Import("example"); // The error at this line.
         int result = python.add(a, b).As<int>();
         return Ok(result);
     }
}
```

The exception goes:

> Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'No module named 'example'.

Comment: You will need to implement a seperate python web api server (django, flask, etc.) and communicate with that server over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't run Python in asp.net core web API project. The exception goes:
> Python.Runtime.PythonException: 'No module named 'example'.

Based on your code snippet and shared error,  indicates that the Python interpreter is unable to find a module named 'example' when attempting to import it.

In your scenario, you're trying to import a module named 'example' in your ASP.NET Core application, but the Python interpreter cannot locate it.

In order to resolve this issue, you should investigate couple of things:

First of all, please validate your execution path is correct. You might have a typo in the import statement, or the path to the `example.py` file might be wrong.

For instance, If example.py is in the project root, then you should try like below:

```
 dynamic python = Py.Import("example");
```

But if your file residing in sub folder then try like this:

```
dynamic python = Py.Import("subdirectory.example");
```

Another important thing is, If `example.py` is not in the default search path for Python, you might need to explicitly add its directory path using `PythonEngine.PythonPath.Add()`

In addition, make sure, `PythonEngine.Initialize()` is called only once, typically in a centralized location like a singleton class.

Finally, Instead of just specifying the module name, try using the absolute path to the 'example.py' file.

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document for configuration](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet).